# comparision function in stl::sort()

Tags: c++, stl

```
class node{
public:
  unsigned long long int value;
  int index;
};


bool comp2(node& a,node& b){
  if(a.value < b.value) { return true; }
  return false;
}

vector <node*>llist,rlist;
sort(llist.begin(),llist.end(),comp2);
```

Above code was giving me some weired error that is too in some other lines(places latter in code), but when i changed comp2 function to following all error disappeared .

```
bool comp2(node* a,node* b){
  assert(a && b && "comp2 - null argument");
  if(a->value < b->value){ return true; }
  return false;
}
```

Any rationale on this ?

ERROR:`/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h|124|error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘node&’ from expression of type ‘node* const’|`

If this(bellow) works then above should also work

```
using namespace std;

void rep(int& a,int& b){

int c;
c=a;
a=b;
b=c;

}

int main(void){

int a=3,b=4;

rep(a,b);
cout<<a<<" "<<b;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the "weird error"?

Comment: @gtk.pro: I took the liberty to refactor (tidy up the formatting, cleaned up the methods).

Comment: @Matthieu: you no doubt made the code better but IMHO it would have been even better had you left the code as-is and posted your refactorings as an answer (yes, off-topic, but such corrections are generally accepted). This gives you the chance to explain *why* you make the refactorings.

Comment: @Konrad: true... but then others would have had to trudge through it (and I am being lazy tonight, week-end effect).

Comment: @Matthieu M: You confused me with your formating what does assert() function mean.

Comment: @gtk.pro: Wikipedia says it better than I do --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29 | if it's too confusing for you, you can simply rollback the edit (use the edit button, there is a combo-box at the top with all the successive edits, you can go back in time!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined a `std::vector` of `node *`.  Therefore, all the elements are `node *`, and all operations that the vector performs will be on `node *`.  You can't give `sort` a comparison function of a different type.

Comment: but I have heard somewhere that using type& a in  function definition you don't have to use *a every where in function you can simply use a (meaning same as *a)

Comment: @gkt: I'm afraid you heard wrong!  Whilst references and pointers serve fairly similar purposes, they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: take a look at the new program that i have added at the end of my question.

Comment: @gkt: I'm not sure I understand what that new program has to do with anything!

Answer (score 3):

The rational is that your vector contains values of type `node*`, so the comparison functions needs to compare values of type `node*`.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably meant to say in the first place was `vector<node>`. If you wanted pointers to nodes, then the second comparison function is reasonable.